# What is the best practise for REST API call?

Tags: java, android, rest, spring-boot

Currently I am working on an Android app what needs to call a Spring Boot REST API for some data stored in DB. What is the best practise to handle REST API calls from Android? I am interesed in the most clear way.

Do I need HTTPS or HTTP is enough? I will storing some user based data, but not like personal.or something. The most personal data would be email address. I am using Java.

Comment: "I will storing some user based data, but not like personal..or something. (The most personal data would be email address)" => The e-mail address is a very personal data!

Comment: Newer versions of Android i.e Android 8 and above, will block all `http://` API calls and fail automatically. Its better to use `https://`

Comment: The widely followed practice is to use Retrofit library which internally uses OkHttp

Comment: I use the Volley library.  It was several times faster than the built-in HTTP request objects.  Definitely use https for any data, whether you think it is private or not.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll check those libs ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Retrofit 2](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) which is a powerful REST API client!

Also I found [Futurestudios tutorials](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client) quite useful to learn how to use it in an android app.

As others already suggested I'd always use `https://` nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Try the MVVM pattern with Repository pattern.

Here are the Architecture samples from Google
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture

Apart from this use Retrofit to make remote API calls. In sample they are mocking the data so replace it with your api call.

Link to retrofit: https://square.github.io/retrofit/

How to consume REST services using Retrofit: https://android.jlelse.eu/consuming-rest-api-using-retrofit-library-in-android-ed47aef01ecb